# JS Function Issues with array.filter()

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

So I have a JavaScript function I'm working on. I noticed that my editor is flagging an error on line 4 but the function works in every browser I've tested except for IE and Safari. I find this particularly weird.

Basic idea for the function is: take 'element' (the ID of a html element) and convert it to a string, define an array of all possible versions of 'element', remove 'element' from the array, and perform another function using the now-filtered array and 'element' as variables. This is what I have:

```
function thisFunction(element){
    var eStr=element.toString();
    var eArray=['element1', 'element2', 'element3'];
    var fArray=eArray.filter(e=>e!==eStr);
    fArray.forEach(doThis);
    function doThis(value){

        Now do this with 'fArray'....

        return false;
        doThis();
        }

    And do this with 'element'...

    return false;
    thisFunction();
    }
```

The error is apparently something to do with the "var fArray" line, but I cant see a problem. The error when I click the link that is supposed to activate this function is "thisFunction is undefined" as well as the error on line 4.

Comment: not really sure what to tell you it seems right to me. Although you will want to replace the `var` with `let` or `const`

Comment: Copy and paste the error.

Comment: What is `element` - "*the ID of a html element*" - if it's not already a string?

Comment: I know it seems right to me too...

Comment: Error is function doesn't work in IE or safari, I get "There is a syntax error on line 4." in code editor and "SCRIPT1002: Syntax error" error in IE console.

well "element" is the id name of an html element, but if I just use "element" instead of converting it to a string it outputs loads of html instead of the html elements id. In Chrome, that is. I haven't tried it without in IE.

Comment: IE does not support the arrow function syntax you've used here: `var fArray=eArray.filter(e=>e!==eStr);` ref: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: @MattHolland that table made my eyes hurt, but I think youre right...

Comment: Safari should support it though - at least in the latest couple of versions...

Comment: I dont know, but you were right. Definitely was the array.filter callback (?) that was causing the issue. See UPDATE above for info. Problem solved, thanks Matt!!

Comment: Cool, I'll add this as an answer for posterity!

Comment: @100000011 -- please don't edit "SOLVED" into the title of your question, or edit an answer into the question itself. If an answer has been found, it should be posted as an answer, and you can upvote or accept it if you found it helpful. On Stack Overflow that's where answers live, not in the main question!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have enough characters to rip into all the changes your and your buddy made to my questions, but I can tell you that it no longer feels authentic and you removed substantial amounts of information and personality. Furthermore, can't answer my own question? What school did you go to my friend? Because I think you have been seriously misinformed. Answering your own question is very simple, look: What is 1 + 2? It's 3 (oops lmao)!! Wow I'm clever not because I know the answer but because I did it myself without witchcraft! Incredible! Or was it witchcraft? :-O!!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem on line 4 is that IE does not support the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) syntax you're using in the callback. Changing this line:

```
var fArray=eArray.filter(e=>e!==eStr);
```

To something like:

```
var fArray=eArray.filter(function(e) { return e!==eStr; });
```

Should fix things.

Details on which JS features are supported by which browsers can be found at https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/